# Addition in "If" Statements

Tags: clock, addition

I just wanted to know how to use addition in an if statement because in the clock I'm making (without applet), I don't know how to set the hours properly. I have "(if seconds == 60) minutes++, but if I do the same with hours, it adds an hour every second. I just want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks :)

EDIT: Thanks everyone, I fixed it. All I have to do now is find an alternative to "\b"! It doesn't look right without it...

Comment: If you could share your entire script, perhaps we could help you find the problem.

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more context, it's hard to guess what you did wrong without seeing the actual code.

Comment: You probably copypasted the code for hours, and changed only a part which checks seconds.

Comment: Try doing `if(seconds % 60 == 0) minutes++` and same for hours, just with 3600.

Comment: import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Clock {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
 int hours = 0;
 int minutes = 0; 
 int seconds = 0;
for (;seconds <= 60; seconds++) {
 Thread.sleep(250);
 if (seconds == 60) minutes++; {
  if (minutes == 60) hours ++; {
  }
 }
 
System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds); {
 if (seconds == 60) seconds = 0;
 }
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

If you please elaborate more it will be helpful to answer.
According to what I understand :-

use brackets as scope for if statement for more line to come under if:-

```
if(seconds==60)
{
    //add your lines here
}
```

Now if you don't want to change hours then:-

```
if(minutes==60)
   hours++;
```

To put it in seconds if statement scope do the following:-

```
if(seconds==60)
{
   seconds=0;     //let the counter of seconds begin once more
   minutes++;
   if(minutes==60){
      minutes=0;     //let the counter of minute begin once more
      hours++;
   }
}
```